# Как реагировать на события переданного во фрейм компонента?

Tags: delphi

Имеем Frame, который через свойство получает компонент извне. Каким образом этот Frame может корректно реагировать на события данного компонента? Компонент может быть любой, Фреймов на форме несколько, компонент получают один и тот же.
Сам компонент про Frame не знает. При перекрытии его обработчика из Frame, теряем возможность использовать это событие на форме.

Как в Delphi корректно подойти к решению такого вопроса?

Comment: То есть у вас Форма, со многими Фреймами, во многие из которых вы передаете один и тот же Компонент? Зачем, какова более высоко-уровневая цель? Возможно это X-Y проблема (http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709).

Comment: @Kromster мб у компонента есть событие обновления данных, он должен уведомить всех "подписчиков".

Comment: @teran, именно так

Comment: @Isaev что значит, что _"Компонент может быть любой"_ насколько любой, что под этим подразумевается? В целом вы можете завести список обработчиков событий, а основной обработчик может дергать все события из списка по очереди.

Comment: @Isaev я когда-то давно пытался что-то [подобное сделать](http://teran.karelia.pro/articles/item_4508.html), мб полезно будет. Но думаю можно и другие подходы найти, там в комментариях есть примеры другие.

Comment: @teran, Скажем так, компонент может быть один из классов, одним из свойств которого является DataSource. Компонент передаётся фрейму, чтобы фрейм имел возможность с этим DataSource работать. (показывать/редактировать/фильтровать данные). хотелось бы чтобы компонент уведомлял всех "подписчиков" о событиях DataSource.

Comment: @teran, да, это то самое. Спасибо за хорошую статью. Буду пробовать идеи из неё и из комментариев к ней. Грусно, что в Delphi эти "MulticastEvents" не реализованы. Часто нужно, придётся наконец написать для этого класс

Comment: @Isaev можно при возникновении события найти на форме все фреймы и разослать им сообщения `WM_USER + X`, которые они обработают. Кому надо, тот обработает, а не надо дак продет мимо.

Comment: @teran, можно, но именно этого и хотелось бы избежать, чтобы этот мусор не разводить в каждом отдельном модуле... В идеале положил фрейм на форму, настроил свойства и он работает.